# Как разместить два изображения рядом друг с другом с positon absolute

Tags: html5, css3

Как можно разместить две картинки рядом, обязательно с `position absolute`?

```css
.rectangle {
   background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZE2q.png) no-repeat;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 559px;
   height: 660px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 15;
}
.rhombus {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ3vk.png) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 660px;
    max-width: 472px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 15;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#FF0000;">
    <div class="logo-block">
        <div class="rectangle"></div>
        <div class="rhombus"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image: rhombus]

[image: rectangle]

Comment: Картинки подобраны ужасно - их не видно на белом фоне! )

Comment: @Kromster, по этому я и убрал их с вопроса и перенёс их в CSS, где они и должны быть.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Если они будут только в теле вопроса, imgur их не потрёт через какое-то время?

Comment: @Kromster, даже не подскажу.. Вопросу уже 3 года, не потёрли ещё))

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Вот даже не знаю .. три года они были в дефолтном месте (т.е. оформлены как внешние ссылки). Если считаете уместным - сделайте откат плиз (только сохраните фон плиз, с ним куда как яснее в чем дело)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставить для второй картинки свойство left:559px;, если известна ширина первой картинки.Если ширина не известна, то можно через js ее получать, и устанавливать left второй картинке.

Comment: спасибо, ответ помог. А можете вот что еще подсказать - размещая изображение через backgraund, я каждый раз прописываю высоту картинки для ее отображения. Но таким образом, она теряет свою адаптивность из за фиксированный высоты. Как можно было бы разместить изображение через bg, так, чтобы адаптивность была?

Comment: Зачем прописывать жесткие размеры? Можно же относительные писать и получится как тебе нужно

Answer (score 1):

```css
.logo-block {
  position: relative;
}

.rectangle {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZE2q.png) no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 559px;
  height: 660px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 15;
}

.rhombus {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ3vk.png) no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 660px;
  max-width: 472px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 15;
  top: 0;
  left: 559px;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:#FF0000;">
<div class="logo-block">
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  <div class="rhombus"></div>
</div>
</body>
```